# Include $scope value with html code and display in html page angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In my controller i have

```
$scope.hello = function(a){
$scope.rr = '<span><i class=" ti-back-right"></i></span>' ;
}
```

In my  html page
If i use

```
{{rr}}
```

I get the output as . But actually i need the icon there.. Please help me.

Comment: why do you need this as string and not put it in the view template or in a directive? Controllers shouldn't be used to manage html... just manage data models that drive the view

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by strict contextual escaping (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Either use

```
<span ng-bind-html={{rr}}>
```

or use

```
$scope.rr = $sce.trustAsHtml('<span><i class=" ti-back-right"></i></span>')
```